# Listening for updates with RESTful APIs

Tags: android, api, api-design

I have a messenger app that makes `GET /conversations` requests to populate a list of the conversations of the user.

The next step is to make it "listen" for updates so that it marks conversations that have been updated and add conversations that have been created.

Should I use the same `/conversations` resource to get the updates or should I rather have a separate resource for that? Perhaps, something like `/conversationUpdates`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want to follow RESTful conventions.  Many client side libraries such as backbone and extjs have fairly deep support for declaring a resource with a URI and then using the different HTTP methods (GET, POST, DELETE, etc.) against it.  This might sometimes lessen the work clients need to do and folks will be grateful.

Following the convention will also make your api less surprising.  There are undoubtedly other conventions for API's and not every domain space is well modeled with REST.

Rereading your post, I see you want to have an api that that just gets new posts.  What constitutes new?  New since the last time the client called the end point?  In such instances an api might accept a parameter like the last identifier that had been received  (if you are using something like a auto increment field, or a mongodb id). In that case you would just use the `/conversations` endpoint, with an extra parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd stick here with the GET method, since this is exactly the point: getting data.

As for the resource name, I'd go  with the same, specifying it further in the query, something like `/conversations?state=new`. My point here is that the resource itself is still the same but you only want a subset of it.

However, if you plan on updating other things than conversations, you can use `/updates/conversations` since in this case, an update can be considered as a resource, itself composed of, among other things, conversations.

Comment: Could u elaborate on the benefits of the suggested approach?

Comment: I'm not an expert in REST Apis. It is just my  opinion it is far-fetched to consider a buch of new X as new resource Y. I'm willing to use a new resource only if the update can be really considered as a new 'complex'  object, not only as a collection of X.
Moreover, if your conversation happens to have a 'date' attribute, then it is classical REST to use the query parameters to specify conditions on your resource attributes.